# Rendering res.locals middleware data on static html

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to render data from res.locals.result on static page "results.html".
How can i pass the data into the view.

I'm not using templating engines.

```
app.post("/post", startLoop, (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('results.html', {"variable":res.locals.result});
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is in results.html? If it's not a template, then it means it's static, so you can't add data to it. To add template support you can use https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express

Comment: use templating engine :)